Solution to PyImport_ImportModule() crashes every time
It's been a long time since I'm trying to figure out the solution to the question that I've asked some time ago:
PyImportModule crashes every time
Finally I figure the solution out and I'll explain how I did  it.
const char* run_python(){
   Py_Initialize();
   PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nsys.stderr = sys.stdout\n");
   PyObject* pModule = Py_None;
   pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("geo");
   PyObject* get_currency = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "get_currency");
   PyObject* currencyPy= PyObject_CallObject(get_currency, NULL);
   const char* currency1 = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(currencyPy);
   if(currency1 == NULL){
      printf("Something went wrong, tou must be connected to the Internet, try again!");
      Py_DecRef(get_currency);
      Py_DecRef(currencyPy);
      Py_DecRef(pModule);
      Py_Finalize();
   } else {
      Py_DecRef(get_currency);
      Py_DecRef(currencyPy);
      Py_DecRef(pModule);
      Py_Finalize();
      return currency1;
   }
}

When I ran it the first time it worked fine, but then the second time it crashes.
To solve the problem I deleted the Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize() functions, and I put the first one and the very start of the program, immediatly after the int main(){ function, and I put the second one at the very end of the program.
So these lines of code run just once, and everything works fine.
The problem was that the first time it loaded and initialized the Python.h module and also it finalized it good, then the second time the module initialization took too many time time and it ws going in TimeLimit error.
I'm so happy to have solved this problem and I'll update my new program on GitHub in a few weeks.
Thanks also to you guys and have a great day.
